# While loop keeps running after break

Tags: c#

I need to download a file and use it to connect to a server. If the connection fails, it restarts the loop. Somehow the while loop keeps running and downloading the file constantly. I think that something weird happens with the boolean **Globals.sockRetry** but I can't find what's really happening.

```
public class Globals
{
    public static string serverIp;
    public static int serverPort;

    public static int sockConn = 0;
    public static bool sockRetry = false;

    public static TcpClient client;
    public static NetworkStream nwStream;
    public static StreamReader reader;
    public static StreamWriter writer;
}

static void connect(Globals g)
{
    Globals.sockConn = 1;

    try
    {
        Globals.client = new TcpClient(Globals.serverIp, Globals.serverPort);
        Globals.nwStream = Globals.client.GetStream();
        Globals.reader = new StreamReader(Globals.nwStream);
        Globals.writer = new StreamWriter(Globals.nwStream);

        Globals.sockConn = 2;

        string inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = Globals.reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // ParseMessage(Globals.writer, inputLine, g);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Globals.sockRetry = true;
        Globals.sockConn = 0;
        return;
    }
}

static void getInfo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(INFO_HOST + INFO_PATH);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            string content;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            string[] contentArray = content.Split(':');

            string serverIp = contentArray[0];
            string serverPortStr = contentArray[1];

            int serverPort = 5000;
            Int32.TryParse(serverPortStr, out serverPort);

            Globals g = new Globals();
            Globals.serverIp = serverIp;
            Globals.serverPort = serverPort;

            while (Globals.sockConn == 0)
            {
                if (Globals.sockRetry == false)
                {
                    connect(g);
                }
                else
                {
                    // error connecting
                    // wait and retry
                    Globals.sockRetry = false;
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                    break;
                }
            }

            continue;
        }
        catch
        {
            // error downloading file
            // wait and retry
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the condition for leaving the while loop? From what I can see, your while loop ends on `continue` and never got a `break` or something else to get out of the loop.

Comment: You know, you could have edited your previous question instead of re-posting a new one...

Comment: Do you mean that your program keeps downloading the file even if the download succeeds? Are you sure the download has succeeded? How did you check whether it succeeded?

Comment: @Vipar the while loop from getInfo never ends, it keeps running but is should be blocked by the connect function until the connection fails.

Comment: @stakx Sorry, I edited the title and code. I know that the download has succeeded with the try/catch, it only should download the file if the connection to the server has failed. If that happens, I use Thread.Sleep to wait some time and restart the loop. It's a one-time loop.

Comment: @MiguelRipoll: What do you mean, the while loop is "blocked by" a function? One suggestion: Do yourself a favour and get rid of all static (global) variables. That should make your program easier to understand and possibly help you find the bug.

Comment: @stakx If the connection to the server has succeeded, the ReadLine function from connect will keep the while from getInfo "blocked" I think. If the value from Globals.sockRetry changes it just get out the connection loop to the download one.

Comment: A while loop cannot be "blocked". It simply dictates program control flow. You can make sure never to get to the start or end of a loop by staying busy inside the loop... but you cannot "block" a loop.

Comment: "While loop keeps running after continue" well, it's how it's supposed to work. If you want to leave the loop use break.

Comment: @stakx Yeah, sorry. I mean that the ReadLine function blocks the current thread.

Comment: You know that you could live happily without those (absolutely unecessary) global variables?

Comment: @AK_ Some advise would help, I'm trying to avoid recursion, but was very confused.

Comment: @khlr You sure? I need to use them on the parseMessage function.

Comment: Well, you didn't show the `parseMessage` method (as it isn't necessary for solving your current problem), but I'm quite sure, that even there you don't really need any globals ;-)

Comment: @khlr Code seems to work right on Windows 8 & 10, still waiting to try this on 7. I removed all the globals except sockConn & sockRetry. These need to be received to the while loop from the connect function, is there a alternative? Thanks by the way!

Comment: Well, then head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ create a new question there, ask for optimization, and share the link here :)

Comment: @khlr I explained better what the program does on code review, I'm sorry for the people on this question now. Here is and thank you for the help. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79297/download-file-and-connect-if-one-of-them-fails-go-to-step-one

Answer (score 5):

The only place there you terminate the loop is here:

```
if (Globals.sockRetry == false)
            {
                connect(g);
            }
            else
            {
                ...
                break;
            }
```

So it happens only if `Globals.sockRetry == true`. `Globals.sockRetry` is assigned `true` only if an exception is thrown. If no exception is thrown, the loop never ends.

Change it like this:

```
   if (Globals.sockRetry == false)
            {
                connect(g);
                break;
            }
```

Otherwise after you connect you will connect again, and then again till an exception is thrown (hopefully).

Comment: Globals.sockRetry is false, if there aren't any exceptions, then it connects and the ReadLine function keeps the while loop busy at that line. What I'm missing?

Comment: `ReadLine` will return false sooner or later, but you call `connect` in an infinite loop. And `connect` calls `ReadLine`. How many times do you need to connect?

Answer (score 1):

`continue` continues to the next iteration in the loop.
`break` stops the loop. So, the loop never ends.

You set `sockRetry` to `false` when you want to stop the loop, so you could do this: `while (sockRetry)`

Comment: I know, I use break to stop the connection loop and continue to download the file again.